# No-MFC equivalent of AfxGetThreadState in vc++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, msg

I am porting a MFC application to Win32 one, I need to get

`AfxGetThreadState()->m_lastSentMsg`

value in Win32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well all MFC is doing is recording what the last message it received was in a class.  I'm sure you could add something like this to your thread message pumps ...

Edit: Also its worth looking at __declspec( thread ) for defining a "global" in the thread local storage.  This is what MFC does ...

Edit: You'll have a message pump.  If you first declare a variable similar to the following:

```
__declspec( thread ) MSG g_LastMsg = 0;
```

And then you need to change your message pump in each thread to something like this:

```
MSG msg;
while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
{
            g_LastMsg = msg;
    TranslateMessage( &msg );
    DispatchMessage( &msg );
}
```

Now any time you want to see what the last message "pumped" was just check the g_LastMsg variable ...

You could also build the message struct from inside your Window procedures if you prefer.  Entirely up to you ...

Comment: Well, in fact I am not that pro on MFC so what where should I record last message?

Comment: @whoi you don't need to be an MFC pro to **not** use MFC. Record it wherever you want!

Comment: @Ben: If you take a look at when he posted and when I edited perhaps the question makes more sense.